# Can I get a shadowbox with rounded corners? (using `listings` package)

Tags: listings, rounded-corners, shadows

I'm using the `listings` package as below:

```
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{pythoncode}[1][]
{\lstset{language=Python,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    frame=shadowbox,
    frameround=tttt,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    rulesepcolor=\color{gray},
    #1}
}{}
```

I wanted to get a rounded corners together with a drop-shadow (shadowbox). Is it possible? While the frame border itself had rounded corners, the shadow had square corners, which is kinda ugly.

Comment: Do you have to use `listings` to create the box? Could you place the listing inside a `tikz` node?  Then you could use something like this: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/

Comment: Well... I don't need. I just didn't know any other way. Maybe you could submit an answer (instead of a comment) containing a sample code? ;) It should work with pdflatex and `beamer` package.

Answer (score 7):

Next code uses `tcolorbox` to format the shadowed box where code is inserted through `listing` package. Size, color and format of shadows can be adapted to ones taste.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[2][]{%
    enhanced, title=#2, colframe=blue!50!black, 
    colback=blue!10!white, 
    fonttitle=\ttfamily, coltitle=white,
    attach boxed title to top left = {xshift=5mm,yshift=-2mm} ,
    boxed title style={size=small, colback=blue!75!black},
    width=.5\linewidth,
    listing only,listing options={language=Python, basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize},#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{pythoncode}[drop shadow]{hello.py}
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    print "Hello, World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
\end{pythoncode}

\begin{pythoncode}[drop fuzzy shadow]{hello.py}
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    print "Hello, World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
\end{pythoncode}

\begin{pythoncode}[drop lifted shadow]{hello.py}
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    print "Hello, World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
\end{pythoncode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice suggestion, is this possible to get the shadow as in gradient format?

Comment: @MadyYuvi What's a gradient format? Do you want to change the darkness? Information about tcolorbox shadows is in section 10.6. But if you know how to do the shadow in `TiKZ` you can also use it with a `tcolorbox` (see section 10.6.4).

Answer (score 4):

do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{demo}
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[shadow]{A listing}
\begin{lstlisting}
foo
bar
baz 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{beamerboxesrounded}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example using TikZ. Also working with beamer

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
  decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
  matrix,shapes.symbols,plotmarks,decorations.markings,shadows}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
  \node[drop shadow,fill=white,draw,rounded corners] 
   {$\sum\limits_{i=1}^N (x_i-\mu_i)^2$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Would have posted a picture, but I dont have enough rep. to do so, yet.

Using a listing could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                              
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
  decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
  matrix,shapes.symbols,plotmarks,decorations.markings,shadows}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Code Listing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lstnewenvironment{CODEENV}{
   \lstset{
     language=Matlab,
     numbers=left,
     numberstyle=\tiny,
     stepnumber=1,
     numbersep=1em,
     tabsize=1,
   }
  }{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
  \node[drop shadow,fill=white,draw,rounded corners,inner sep=1em] {
  \begin{CODEENV}
N = 128;
sigma_r = 1;

% Leistungsdichte nach Clark
nu_max      = 1;
nu          = (-nu_max):(2*nu_max/(N-1)):(nu_max);

% Bessel & Clark
xlambda = (0:2/(N-1):2);
rho_R = sigma_r^2*besselj(0, 2*pi*xlambda);

figure;
subplot(211);
plot(xlambda,rho_R/max(rho_R));
subplot(212);
plot(nu, abs(fft(rho_R)).^2);
 \end{CODEENV}
};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, that if you have long code snippets, you may need to increase the 'inner sep' parameter of the node, as the line numbering is done outside the listing box (as it seems).

Comment: The tricky part is not creating the shadow box, but making it work together with listings.

Comment: You are right. It was a little tricky