# Background overflows when using rounded corners for listings (package: `listings`)

Tags: listings, color, backgrounds, rounded-corners

I'm using `listings` to list code in my document, and I want the code to be displayed in a frame with rounded corners and a grey background color. But the background overflows the frame, as if the frame was square.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, xleftmargin=1em, xrightmargin=1em,
  frame=single, framesep=1em, frameround=tttt,
  backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}, captionpos=b}
\begin{lstlisting}
bla bla bla
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: result]

Any idea on how to fix this?

## EDIT

I got the example working now. The problem was due to old versions of required packages.

Comment: I added a picture to make the problem visible. Se also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/can-i-get-a-shadowbox-with-rounded-corners-using-listings-package which seems to be nearly the same question …

Comment: Could you specify which are the required packages? According to MiKTeX, all my packages are up to date, but I still have the same issue. In the listings document I could only find a mention of `keyval` from the the `graphics` package, which is up to date.

Comment: Oh. Are the "old versions of required pacakages" reffering to the accepted answer? I.e. `etoolbox`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the link in my comment I created an environment in which you can use the `lstlistings`-environment:

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

%\usepackage{color} loaded by tikz and you should use xcolor instead ...
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

% set listings
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
%   captionpos=t,
    framesep=5em,
}

% define backgroundcolor
\definecolor{bggray}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}

% add frame environment
\usepackage[%
    framemethod=tikz,
    skipbelow=\topskip,
    skipabove=\topskip
]{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{%
    leftmargin=0pt,
    rightmargin=0pt,
    backgroundcolor=bggray,
    middlelinecolor=black,
    roundcorner=10
}

\usepackage{etoolbox}% >= v2.1 2011-01-03
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\begin{mdframed}\vspace{-0.7em}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\vspace{-0.5em}\end{mdframed}}

% needed for \lstcapt
\def\ifempty#1{\def\temparg{#1}\ifx\temparg\empty}

% make new caption command for listings
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\lstcapt}[2][]{%
    \ifempty{#1}%
        \captionof{lstlisting}{#2}%
    \else%
        \captionof{lstlisting}[#1]{#2}%
    \fi%
    \vspace{0.75\baselineskip}%
}

% only for testing ...
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
%
\begin{lstlisting}
Foo {
    Bazzzzz }
Bar
\end{lstlisting}
\lstcapt{Test}
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{lstlisting}
Foo
\end{lstlisting}
\lstcapt[Short descrpition]{Another long description. Another long description.
    Another long description.}
%
\blindtext
%
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

### Result

[image: result]

### <strike>Limitation</strike>

This solution works only for non page breaking listings. See the answers to [Test if a paragraph has a page break in it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21521/test-if-a-paragraph-has-a-page-break-in-it/21522#21522) for an idea how this could work.
**See Update 3**

### Update

I put this three lines to the above example to patch the `lstlisting` environment dircetly. So there’s no need to put it manually in `\begin{code} … \end{code}` anymore.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\begin{code}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\end{code}}
```

### Update 2

I created a new command `\lstcapt[<Short>]{<Text>}` to set a caption out of the frame, and added it to the above example code.

### Update 3

I changed to mdframed instead of using TikZ directly to solve the page breaking problem as Marco suggested.

### Update 4

Please note that this code needs `etoolbox` v2.1 or higer …

### Update 5: Filelist

This is the result of `\filelist` before `\documentclass`

```
*File List*
article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size11.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
listings.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
keyval.sty 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
lstmisc.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg 2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
tikz.sty 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
pgf.sty 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
pgfrcs.sty 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfcore.sty 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
ltxcmds.sty 2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pgfsys.sty 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16 (rcs-revision 1.4)
xcolor.sty 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
pgffor.sty 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
pgfkeys.sty
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
mdframed.sty 2011/08/06 v0.7a: mdframed
kvoptions.sty 2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty 2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty 2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
ifluatex.sty 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
etex.sty 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
calc.sty 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
etoolbox.sty 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
md-frame-1.mdf 2011/08/06 v0.7a: md-frame-1
caption.sty 2011/08/18 v3.2b Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty 2011/08/18 v1.3b caption3 kernel (AR)
babel.sty 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
english.ldf 2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
blindtext.sty 2009/12/29 V1.9c blindtext-Package
xspace.sty 2009/10/20 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty 2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifpdf.sty 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
grfext.sty 2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
***********
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get your example to compile. It says: ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \BeforeBeginEnvironment 
                                        
l.38 \BeforeBeginEnvironment
                            {lstlisting}{\begin{code}}

Comment: Hm, I can't get it working satisfactory. First, the listing is indented about an inch or so within the shaded box. Second, the caption is also included into the box (this I do not want).

Comment: @gablin: Sorry for forgetting the caption, se my 2nd update. I can’t follow your second problem with indenting. Could you provide an example (and a picture) and add it to your original question please?

Comment: Done. I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. And I keep getting this error when I try using `etoolbox`. Maybe it hasn't been probably installed or something (although the package does exist and comes bundled with TeXLive).

Comment: @Tobi: Sorry for the counterexample.

Comment: @gablin: 1. The problem with indenting can be caused by indents of the code in your document since `lstlisting` takes it’s contents verbatim it also takes the line indention of the source code.

Comment: @gablin: 2. Could you please run the code of my answer with no changes and tell me if there are problems and maybe upload the `.log` file?

Comment: @Tobi: With `style=1` you used tikz ;-)

Comment: @gablin: 3. The warning about using `\captionof` outside a box can be ignored I guess … I think it’s not happy to be outside a (float) environment, but it works.

Comment: @Tobi: Well, with the new example at least the indentation has disappeared. However, I still have the problem that `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` doesn't work (says it's undefined even though the package is installed), and that the listings are unnumbered in the caption.

Comment: @gablin: Which TeX versrion are you using? I’m workin with TeX Live 2011. Did you try to make an update? If an update doesn’t fix your problem send me your log file, please.

Comment: It appears I got TexLive 2009-10 installed, which is also the latest "version" according to Ubuntu. Wonder how I'll get 2011 installed...

Comment: @gablin: Ahh, the `\AtBeginEnvironment` is new in `etoolbox` v2.1. I don’t know how to update on linux but I’m sure there is a way. As a workaround you could install the new `etoolbox` directly.

Comment: @gablin: If an update isn’t possible you could write `\begin{mdframed}\vspace{-0.7em}\begin{lstlisting} ... \end{lstlisting}\vspace{-0.5em}\end{mdframed}` to get the right formatting.

Comment: @Tobi: Yep, that's what I've done to get the example to compile. But I still don't get any listings number printed in the caption; instead I get "Listing: yadda yadda yada".

Comment: @gablin: I’m sorry but I still can’t reproduce your numbering problem. Maybe some more packages are outdated (?). I added my file list so you can check what the problem could be … However I recommend to update to TL2011.

Comment: @Tobi: Yeah, I'll try updating to TeXLive 2011 and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @Tobi: Ah, _now_ I got everything working; I ran it on my Windows machine after having updated all installed packages in MiKTeX (I think I must have had an old version of `caption` which caused the listings number to be missing, and that's probably the same problem I have on my Ubuntu laptop). Thanks for all your help. I'm installing TeXLive 2011 on my laptop as we speak. ^^

Comment: Cursed! When I tried moving the example code into my document, the labels got completely screwed up. Since this is only a minor detail, I'll give up on getting rounded corners in my listings for now...

Comment: @gablin: Could you pleas explain what you mean with “ labels got completely screwed up”? You could also adda picture to your original question … Maybe there are some conflicts with other packages … try this: Copy your code to a new document and delete everything step by step until the error is a way, then you know where the problem is caused and create a minimal example to append it to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the package `mdframed` which allows page breaking:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    abovecaptionskip=0pt,belowcaptionskip =0pt,
    framextopmargin=-\topsep, 
}

% define backgroundcolor

\usepackage[style=1,skipbelow=\topskip,skipabove=\topskip]{mdframed}
\definecolor{bggray}{rgb}{0.85, 0.85, 0.85}
\mdfsetup{leftmargin=20pt,rightmargin=20pt,backgroundcolor=bggray,middlelinecolor=black,roundcorner=15}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\begin{mdframed}\vskip-.5\baselineskip}
\AfterEndEnvironment{lstlisting}{\end{mdframed}}

% only for testing ...
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
%
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=foo]
Foo {
    Bazzzzz }
Bar
\end{lstlisting}
%\lstcapt{Test}
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{lstlisting}
Foo

Foo {
    Bazzzzz }
Bar


Foo {
    Bazzzzz }
Bar


Foo {
    Bazzzzz }
Bar

Foo {
    Bazzzzz }
Bar

Foo {
    Bazzzzz }
Bar

Foo {
    Bazzzzz }
Bar
\end{lstlisting}
\blindtext
%
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for solving the page breaking problem in an easy way. I added your solution to my code, hope that’s ok with you?

Comment: @Tobi: Now problem. But I will add this code to my documentation.

Comment: So `mdframed` is your package? And it uses TikZ internally?

Comment: Checkt it on CTAN myself. Seems to be a useful package :-) Greetings from Osnabrück ;-)

Comment: @Tobi: "Die Nordlichter" ;-)

Comment: Nicht so nördlich wie gablin …

Comment: Hey, what are you guys saying about me? =P

Comment: @gablin: Tobi and I from the north of Germany. We call such people as "Nordlichter". But Tobi mentioned that you are the real "Nordlicht" ;-)

Comment: @gablin: Sorry for talking german O:-) Goole says: “The Northern Lights” “Not as far north as gablin” ;-) Marco explained it I think. (Maybe we should delete this comments since they aren’t useful for the community …)

Comment: @Tobi: Au contraire! I find it very useful to know what "The Northern Lights" is in German. Ops, now I involved a bit of French there... =P

Comment: @gablin: :-) But in german “Nordlichter“ is not only the name of a [http://www.google.com/search?q=nordlicht&hl=de&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=XR5uTuOPJoTFswaXw-zpCg&ved=0CEMQsAQ&biw=1273&bih=702](physical phenomenon) but also a metaphor for the people living in the northern part of the country …