# How can I prevent the background from overlapping the rounded corners in an \lstinputlisting?

Tags: listings, backgrounds

I want to include listings of external files in my document. These listings should have a solid background and rounded corners. The problem is, that if I define a style with `frameround` and `backgroundcolor`, the background overlaps the rounded corners.

```
\lstdefinestyle{cftemplate}{
    frameround=tttt,
    rulecolor=\color[rgb]{0.7, 0.7, 0.7},
    frame=single,
    backgroundcolor=\color[rgb]{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
}
```

There already exists a question [how this behavior can be prevented in a `lstlisting`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27673/background-overflows-when-using-rounded-corners-for-listings-package-listings). In particular the [solution presented in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27676/15387) works well for me. So I tried to extend this solution so that it also works with `\lstinputlisting`. However, the obvious attempt to replace "lstlisting" with "lstinputlisting" in the code snippet did not work.

So my question is: **How can I create a \lstinputlisting with a background and rounded corners, where the background does not overlap the rounded corners?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are willing to use the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package and its `listings` library, this is easy; using `\newtcbinputlisting` you can define a customizable macro which behaves pretty much as `\lstinputlisting` and with `\newtcblisting` you define your customizable version of `lstlisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}% just for the example
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcbinputlisting{\myinputlisting}[2][]{%
  listing engine=listings,
  listing file={#2},
  colback=red!15,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  arc=12pt,
  listing only,
  listing options={
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
  },
  breakable,
  #1
}
\newtcblisting{mylisting}[1][]{%
  listing engine=listings,
  colback=red!15,
  colframe=red!75!black,
  arc=12pt,
  listing only,
  listing options={
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
  },
  breakable,
  #1
}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Gtest1.tex}  
\newlength\mylena
\newlength\mylenb
\setlength\mylena{2cm}
\setlength\mylenb{4cm}
\addtolength\mylena{\mylenb}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\myinputlisting{Gtest1.tex}

\begin{mylisting}[]
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It was a bit tricky, because apparently I had an outdated version of the `tcolorbox` package. But now it looks very nice. Thanks!